# How to Downgrade CentOS 7.2 to 7.1 on Linode？

Tags: centos, kernel

I can change Kernel on Linode Manager page, but I don't know how to Downgrade CentOS 7.2 to 7.1

Comment: If the upgrade was recent you can use `yum history undo <transactionID>`  to undo the transaction and downgrade the appropriate packages. You can list available ID's by just running `yum history` and looking through the list.

Comment: Why are you wanting to do that, though?

Answer (score 2):

You can have a look at this procedure for reference.

```
# yum history
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
ID     | Login user               | Date and time    | Action(s)      | Altered
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    68 |  <p15119007g>            | 2016-02-27 01:40 | I, U           |   27
    67 |  <a15099004r>            | 2016-02-25 03:05 | Install        |    1
    66 |  <a15099004r>            | 2015-12-28 05:39 | Install        |    1
    65 |  <a15099004r>            | 2015-12-18 03:53 | Update         |    1
    64 |  <a15099004r>            | 2015-12-18 03:53 | Update         |    3 EE
```

You Can get information by this command

```
]# yum history info 67
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Transaction ID : 67
Begin time     : Thu Feb 25 03:05:33 2016
Begin rpmdb    : 490:72cf901a0f20ed46ebf4f2a1fbd5b59cde29cd80
End time       :            03:05:38 2016 (5 seconds)
End rpmdb      : 491:fa86b8767c48011cab7b19968339fc95b38f0475
User           :  <a15099004r>
Return-Code    : Success
Command Line   : install mlocate
Transaction performed with:
    Installed     rpm-4.8.0-47.el6.x86_64                       @base
    Installed     yum-3.2.29-69.el6.centos.noarch               @base
    Installed     yum-plugin-fastestmirror-1.1.30-30.el6.noarch @base
Packages Altered:
    Install mlocate-0.22.2-6.el6.x86_64 @base
history info
```

`undo` will remove the installed package

```
 # yum history undo 2
```

Comment: In your example，should I use this command： # yum history undo 67 ?  I try this method, but it doesn't work at Linode.com

Comment: It should work as shown in my example its working.