# How to downgrade kernel on CentOS 7

Tags: centos, kernel, linux-kernel

I am having the issue mentioned here https://community.freepbx.org/t/solved-sort-of-wanpipe-fails-to-compile-on-new-kernel-3-10-0-862-2-3-el7-x86-64/50151 I am unable to figure out how to install a specific kernel version. I had a look at [How to Downgrade CentOS 7.2 to 7.1 on Linode？](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/269834/how-to-downgrade-centos-7-2-to-7-1-on-linode) but that does not help me as the box comes with 3.10.0-862.9.1.el7.x86_64 and has no history of 3.10.0-693.17.1.el7.x86_64

Comment: 1) Are you sure your issue cannot be solved by upgrading instead of downgrading? 2) Can you not download the old kernel and install with `rpm`? What have you tried and what issues are you facing?

Comment: @ajeh If the machine already has `3.10.0-862.9.1.el7.x86_64` then he can't upgrade as that's already the latest available kernel for `CentOS 7`.

Comment: @NasirRiley I generally stick with the distro supplied kernels, but is it not possible to install a newer generic kernel? Or a kernel from Fedora, which is very similar?

Comment: @ajeh In this case, it can't be installed from CentOS's repos as they will only have what's available for the specific distro. It's possible to source-compile a kernel or install an rpm for a kernel from Fedora but it's usually a bad idea for the same reason that installing an rpm from Fedora is a bad idea.

Comment: So d/l an older kernel and installing it with `rpm` (perhaps by forcing if necessary) remains.

Answer (score 1):

I did not find any work around. The only solution was to install an older version of CentOS that ships with an older kernel. I needed kernel-headers as well and for that I installed them via RPM.